# How to exclude an item from the best-sellers magento

Tags: magento-1.9, best-seller

I have a free gift item but it gets into the best sellers category. is there an easy way to exclude it for getting into the best sellers?

Comment: how do you getting the best sellers products?

Comment: I have a module Mconnectsolutiions_Bestsellerproducts. It's a pretty long template, not sure how to post it but the relevant line seems to be this: $bestsellerproducts = Mage::getModel('bestsellerproducts/bestsellerproducts')->load($bestsellerproductObj->getId()); not sure if thats helpful.

Comment: I guess you can simply check the specific gift item and remove it from the collection?